# How can I "generalize" what R uses as my x and y values in a plot

Tags: r, plot

I have written an executable script in R that will simply plot a graph given an input file in a tab delimited format.  However, the script I wrote is specific to a single file in terms of what to use as x and y.  I want to have this script be able to plot whatever file I give it.  All files I will be using for this script will be in the same format: Tab delimited with 4 headers with labels a, b, c, d.  Labels b,c, and d have a different name for each file. My x values for the graph will be the values under header b and y values for the graph will be the values under header c.  How can I plot a graph that will use whatever is under header b and c?

My script is posted below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
data = read.table((args[1]), header=TRUE, fill=TRUE,  sep="\t")
attach (data)
jpeg(args[2])
plot (RPMb, RPMc)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `attach()` (which is almost never recommended), use data frame indexing to extract the relevant variables from your `data` variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
data = read.table((args[1]), header=TRUE, fill=TRUE,  sep="\t")
jpeg(args[2])
x <- names(data)[2]
y <- names(data)[3]
plot (data[[x]], data[[y]],xlab=x,ylab=y)
dev.off()
```

You could also just use `plot(data[,2],data[,3])` ...

A couple of other details/comments:

- it's generally best to avoid naming variables for built-in functions such as `data`. It will usually work, but occasionally it will bite you.
- are you sure you want JPEG output?  Either PNG or PDF are usually best for line graphs, depending on whether you need a raster or a vector format ...

Comment: Oh awesome thank you so much! I haven't decided what I want the file output to be yet. I was more just messing around trying to get this script written and get a simple output.  The end goal of this is to try and make a 3d parallel coordinate plot where each plane is one of these scatterplots.